# Android API 7 - AppCompat Theme Custom Font

Tags: android, android-layout, android-appwidget, android-styles, android-appcompat

Trying to Add App Support **Android 2.0** or **API Level 7** Support to my application (Current Support is only for the versions of 3.0 & 4.+). as android suggests, i added AppCompat Lib and changed minSDK to 7.

but the problem is i used following style for the buttons

```
<style name="buttonText" parent="@android:style/TextAppearance">
    <item name="android:textSize">16sp</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/linecolor</item>
    <item name="android:fontFamily">sans-serif</item>  <!-- This one not accepting -->
</style>
```

`fontFamily` is not available and says "**FontFamily requires API Level 16(Current 7)**"

I would like to know what is the alternative way to solve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

You mustnt use android: prefix just use it like

```
<item name="fontFamily">sans-serif</item>
```

if you added the support library truely.

Comment: `<style name="EditTextStyle" parent="@android:style/Widget.EditText">
        <item name="fontFamily">sans-serif</item>
    </style>
    `  

I already tried but it says No resource that matches the given name: att `fontFamily`